# Is there any way to get a Flickr image of custom dimensions?

Tags: images, flickr

There are several custom sizes offered by Flickr available [here](https://www.flickr.com/help/photos/#150488231), but is there any way to get an image of custom dimensions? Say for an example I want an image which should be of 32x32px.

This is available in Google Picasa where I can easily get a custom size of my requirement 
example.

```
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-j_XMBvp8FcI/U58wY6FypjE/AAAAAAAAByA/pygzRmiBneI/**s32-c**/DropBox.jpg
```

As in the above example, the size of the image is given in the link.

I am looking for the same in Flickr if avilable.

Answer (score 2):

You can resize any image from any domain using [Sencha.io Src](http://www.sencha.com/learn/how-to-use-src-sencha-io/) service.

Append the URL of the image to be resized to the end of the Sencha.io Src URL while also specifying the desired dimensions in the URL:

```
http://src.sencha.io/32/32/http://example.com/670image.jpg
```

Update on 4/Sep/15 - The above Sencha feature appears to be unavailable now. However there is an [undocumented Google image resizing feature that works similarly](https://carlo.zottmann.org/2013/04/14/google-image-resizer/)